# FittedBox with fitHeight renders rest of the image width

Tags: flutter, dart

In the example below, FittedBox does what I want: it fits the height into the container. However, it should hide the remaining of the image. However, it renders it.

What is wrong?

[image]

```
/// Flutter code sample for Expanded

// This example shows how to use an [Expanded] widget in a [Column] so that
// its middle child, a [Container] here, expands to fill the space.
//
// ![This results in two thin blue boxes with a larger amber box in between.](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/expanded_column.png)

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Expanded Column Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E5fD0SSqPa0/maxresdefault.jpg'))
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html, it should fit the height but ignore the remaining of the image

Comment: Since the fitted box has space to the left and right it renders the image. I see nothing wrong here.

Comment: @MindStudio please look at my update. I made the width of the parent of the `Expanded`s to have a width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove your FittedBox and set the `fit` property to value `BoxFit.cover` directly to the Image.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Expanded Column Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            width: 100,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E5fD0SSqPa0/maxresdefault.jpg',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But what if I really needed to fix a widget instead of an image?

Comment: For a widget you could just define it so that it expanded in width and height inside the container. That would be much less of a problem imo.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `clipBehavior` to the `FittedBox`, e.g.:

```
Expanded(
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            child: Image.network('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E5fD0SSqPa0/maxresdefault.jpg')
        )
    ),
),
```

For more information see this link [breaking-changes/clip-behavior](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/clip-behavior)